# RichTextBlock PointerPressedEvent - pointer position when selecting a text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, richtextblock

I am developping a windows store application. In my page, I have a RichText**Block** (and not a RichText**Box** as in WPF).

I'd like to subscribe to the `PointerPressed` event. In my constructor, I have the following

```
   rtb.PointerPressed += RtbOnPointerPressed;
    rtb.PointerReleased += RtbOnPointerReleased;
```

My problem is that these events are **never** fired.

If I put a grid on top of my RichTextBlock (**TopGrid** in my code), I can capture the pointerPressed event. However, I can no longer select a text in my RichTextBlock.

If I try to capture the `pointerPressed` event at the container level (**Container** in the code below), it works on if I press in the margins not when I select a text.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Container">//at this level, pointerPressed is raised
           //only when I click outside the richtextblock

       <RichTextBlock x:Name="rtb"></RichTextBlock>//PointerPressed is never fired
       <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="TopGrid"></Grid>//If present,
       //the selection does not work on RichTextBlock" 
       //but I can capture the pointerPressed event
    </Grid>
```

Does anyone here know how to know the pointer position when selecting a text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle SelectionChanged event. Sender will have SelectionStart, SelectionEnd and SelectedText properties.

If you for some reason want to use Pressed/Released events replace your code with:

rtb.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(RtbOnPointerPressed), true);

rtb.AddHandler(PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(RtbOnPointerReleased), true);

The last parameter handledEventsToo has to be set to true to make sure that the handler will be invoked even if the event is handled somewhere else.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed you should be aware of the fact that PointerPressed and PointerReleased are not always occuring in pairs.